# Github: Merge `master` branch into `feature` branch after submiting pull request

Tags: git, github, github-cli

I am not sure if it's even feasible. I have tried few things like rebasing/merge but whatever i have tried always comes into the PR diff.

Here is what i have and waht i want,

I have a master (default) branch, then i created a feature branch to make changes and raised a PR against it.

Now more changes have been merged into Master and I need to consume those changes to fix the review comments (mainly some utilities usage and libs). So, essentially i tried rebasing/merge both separately to see how it goes and I always end up with additional commits as changes in my PR diff and not just my changes.

Is there any way to achieve this in github? other than just creating a new feature branch and creating new PR and abandoning old one.

EDIT:

Here is what i have tried,

```
1. Using Rebase
> git checkout master
> git checkout -b feature
> // make changes & commit on feature
> git push origin feature
> git checkout master
> // made some changes & commit on master
> git push origin master

// now rebase
> git checkout feature
> git rebase master
> git push origin feature // fails as it complains HEAD being different from remote feature branch due to earlier rebase
> git pull --rebase
> git push origin feature


This set-up is adding master changes in the PR as diff and commit-id is changed in feature branch as well (expected due to rebase).
```

whereas same set of steps except for rebase, if i do merge then, it doesn't show in PR diff.

Finally after going over few more posts, here is what works and doesn't result master changes to pop-up in PR (w/ rebase option)

```
> git checkout master
> git checkout feature
> //make change & commit
> git push origin feature
> git checkout master
// make change & commit
> git push origin master
> git checkout feature
> git rebase origin/master // you can do just master to rebase against local
> git push -f origin feature // this is important otherwise you will see error and it will ask to do `git pull --rebase origin feature` which will cause master changes to appear in the diff. I feel like github has issues...and it's should do diff based on content rather than commits. but any ways
```

Comment: Are all of your new commits that you wish to PR into `master` linear, and at the "top" of your branch?

Comment: I am pulling in commits from master in between actually. So, let’s say master has c1, feature has c1, then i pushed c2 into feature and raised a PR. Now, In the meantime master for c3. So now when I merge or rebase c3 into feature, it’s getting added to PR diff with my feature c4. So now my PR has c2, c3,c4 against the master. And everything from c3 is reflecting as my change which is not what I want

Comment: OK, regarding this: "when I merge or rebase c3 into feature", you really only need one of those, and regardless of which one you choose, if done correctly you shouldn't be changing the commit ID of `c3` on your branch. (Changing the commit ID is presumably why it's showing up as your change in the PR.) If you provide the exact commands you used maybe we can identify where it went wrong. And, if you want to show your current graph of the two branches we can help you fix it up, and provide the proper steps moving forward.

Comment: Side note, your last sentence of "creating a new feature branch and creating a new PR" should be the same thing as "fixing up your feature branch and force pushing it to reuse the current PR". So I don't see any reason you need a new PR. If you're comfortable creating a new feature branch locally using cherry-picks, you can do that, and then set the upstream to the old remote branch name, or even rename your new local branch to the old one and then force push it.

Comment: Let me create a simulation of the same on github separately for this and will share here. I don't know..very likely it's due to remote pushed commits on my feature branch before a rebase and more on the top

Comment: @TTT as you said, commitId is re-written here and added to diff. 

https://github.com/behinddwalls/reader-app/pull/8


I did rebase from master and then make edit to READ.me file and had pull --rebase on so-feature and then pushed to remote so-feature. 


the commit from master is not same as it is on the master branch so now i have this extra file in PR showing up.

Comment: Good edit. It's now clear exactly why that happened. I've added an answer which explains it.

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happened is because you rebased your new (correct) version of your `feature` branch on top of the old (out of date) version of it. This rewrote not only your commit, but also the new commits you had from `master` which weren't yet on your old copy of your `feature` branch.

The solution, which you've already discovered from the comments and your updated question, can be summarized as:

> When you use a rebase workflow, you need to force push your personal feature branches afterwards.

(Side note: you should rarely, if ever, force push *shared* branches such as `master`.)

The series of commands you used which enabled you to skip the force push:

```
git pull --rebase
git push origin feature
```

meant that you rebased (replayed) all of your commits (which included new commits on `master` too) onto the old version of your branch, and then pushed that out.

Note that in general, I rarely ever pull in favor of explicit fetching. So to update your `feature` branch with the latest `master`, you can do this as often as you like (but perhaps at least once per day):

```
git fetch
git rebase origin/master feature

# If you want to update a PR, or even just backup your commits in case your machine dies
git push --force-with-lease
```

Note the rebase command above will work even if you don't currently have `feature` checked out. If you do already have it checked out, you can leave off the last argument of the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't this just rebasing on (remote) develop? You can totally do that while having a PR open. To do so, checkout your feature branch

```
git checkout branch
```

then fetch the new changes in remote code

```
git fetch upstream
```

and implement them

```
git rebase upstream/master
```

or

```
git rebase upstream/develop
```

depending on where the changes in the remote repo where merged.

BTW, many people prefer merge the remote changes in their own `master` or `develop`, and then rebase their `feature` on their own local `develop`. This is because many devs prefer to have a local clean copy to keep things organized.

Let me know if I'm missing something.

Comment: The problem i am having is that the rebase or merge are bringing other people changes into my PR when i try to make changes on top and update existing PR.

Comment: I, like you, initially saw the word "develop" in the question and assumed it was a branch name, but I think it's actually the verb "develop" as in "work on".

Comment: @TTT yeah it's really not clear to whoever reads the question :/

Comment: i believe i was missing `git push -f` after rebase to push my changes. I was rebasing from master and then i couldn't push as HEAD was different and it kept complaining so i did git pull --rebase origin feature which sort of ruined the whole diffing and added all rebased changed to PR from master.